# Who came up with the name for the demon?

Tags: the-conjuring-2, the-conjuring-universe

In **[The Conjuring 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Conjuring_2)**, in the dinning  room  and library where the demon's name appears, is that Mr. Wan's idea or something the Warren's noticed after the fact?

Comment: What library and dining room? What do you mean by Mr Wan's idea?

Comment: @BlueMoon93 James Wan is the director of the film.

Comment: Related http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55542/why-would-the-demon-do-this-in-the-conjuring-2 and http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61534/is-there-any-religious-ground-for-a-demon-to-give-up-its-name

Answer (score 1):

The name "Valak" is given to the demon in The Conjuring 2, and it's the same demon hinted at in the first Conjuring film, as well as the main villain in The Nun. The idea was based on occult accounts of "Valac", a demon mentioned in the Lesser Key of Solomon and a few other grimoires. Depending on the source, it is also spelled Ualac or Valak. He is described as being one of the leaders ("presidents") among demons and of having the power to summon, find, and control snakes.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valac)